# when I apply transform for scale on my rig, the head spreads apart

Tags: rigging

[image]

the head spreads apart and it should approximately be located around the face.

Comment: Apply *All Transformations* to the *metarig*, then generate the animation rig ("rig") and it should have the correct size. Finally, make the *rig* a parent of the mesh.